# Issue with rawquery SQL Android

Tags: android, sql

I am building a contact app which is using SQL database. I have a search function for user. User can search by key in an alphabet and then the list will show from the alphabet to `z`. For example, if user key is `t`, the list will show contact names starting from `t` to `z`. I create a table whose name is `contactstable` and store contact name in `sname`. Below is my code. However, it fails to search. Can anyone please help me?

```
 public void search(View view) {
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, sname FROM contactstable WHERE sname LIKE ? ORDER BY sname COLLATE NOCASE", 
                    new String[]{"["+searchText.getText().toString() + "-z]%"});
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.employee_list_item, 
            cursor, 
            new String[] {"sname"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.firstName});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the same method as the answer of below post and solve my problem.

[How to use [charlist] Wildcard in android sql search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675435/how-to-use-charlist-wildcard-in-android-sql-search/8675466#8675466)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, it seems the SQLite cannot use

```
A Like B
```

You need to use the function

```
Like(B, A)
```

Please refer to [the SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#like)

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I can see that you are trying to use regular expression with `LIKE` operator, which is not valid.