# How to use [charlist] Wildcard in android sql search

Tags: sql

I tried to search a for name that starts with a or b or c, so I used this query:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, freq FROM dicttable WHERE name LIKE '[A,B,C]%'
    ORDER BY freq DESC LIMIT 0, 8", null);
```

It did not give null result or fail result, it just gave empty values which means it found nothing. Can anyone guide me on this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that sort of thing with `LIKE`. You'll need to use `GLOB` like so:

```
...WHERE name GLOB '[ABC]*' ...
```

The `*` means anything else, so this will match any name that starts with A, B, or C and has anything else following it.

Comment: icic, thanks for pointing out that, however android do not support REGEXP which means I cant use that too, any other methods to search a name that start with a/b/c without using REGEXP '^[ABC]'?

Comment: I didn't realize that. You can also use GLOB. It's a very similar syntax, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It works, thanks alot~! by the way, can I search a word that start with a/b/c and second word d/e/f , so i put my code as GLOB '[ABC]*' '[DEF]' ?

Comment: I cant vote up your answer as accepted answer as I have less than 15 reputation, sorry for that

Comment: Two words in the same string? Use `GLOB '[ABC]* [DEF]*'`, assuming there has to be a space between the words.

Comment: Ya, two words in the same string, it is possible to search a word that has no space in between? lets say i want to search ad/be/cf, how can i search it? By using : GLOB '[ABC][DEF]*' ?

Comment: Ok, I just tested with  GLOB '[ABC][DEF]*' and it can used. Thanks alot for the guide and kind helping hands